# PHP open link in new tab

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

How to add target "blank" to a link in Wordpress "functions.php". The link which opens in same window is:

```
<a href=\"".$widj_options['link']."\" class=\"btn-bg btn-bg-widget w-button\">".$widj_options['title']."</a>
```

For some reason adding the target blank before the href doesn't work:

```
<a target = '_blank' href=\"".$widj_options['link']."\" class=\"btn-bg btn-bg-widget w-button\">".$widj_options['title']."</a>
```

Comment: What about adding it behind the href attribute?

Comment: Are you sure its not the browser settings that are stopping it opening in a new tab?

Comment: I can NOT repro this error. When I copy paste the exact same `<a>`, and test it in JSFiddle it works and opens another tab. https://jsfiddle.net/ha4d9bxf/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Yeah, not sure what's going on. Browser settings should not be the problem since opening links in new tab usually works. Also tried adding it behind does not produce the desired results...

Comment: I see no problems in the given code. other than I hate your way of concatenating your PHP and html. This way of escaping makes my toes tinkle..

Comment: Using inspect element shows that target is not in code... So something must prevent it from outputting the target.

Answer (score 1):

please remove the space after target

```
<a target='_blank' href=\"".$widj_options['link']."\" class=\"btn-bg btn-bg-widget w-button\">".$widj_options['title']."</a>
```

Comment: This will have no effect

Comment: if not working either then i think, maybe something wrong with browser setting please try with different browser

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

```
<a target='_blank' href='".$widj_options['link']." class='btn-bg btn-bg-widget w-button'>".$widj_options['title']."</a>
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to add a description of what it is that you have changed _and why_

Comment: This will have no effect

Answer (score 0):

Remove space `target="_blank"`

OR

> You are doing it right, so we need to check for
>   incompatibility issues. Please try with no extra plugins enabled (Only
>   Toolset) and with a default WordPress theme.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add like that.

```
<a target ='_blank' href='<?=$widj_options['link']?>' class='btn-bg btn-bg-widget w-button'><?=$widj_options['title']?></a>
```

Comment: This will have no effect

Comment: Did you check the code with inspect element on front-end? What did you see?

Comment: @SuYatanar Inspect element does not show target blank.... even though it has been added to the code.